# Email Templates in AddThis

Tags: addthis

I have created an email template and set it as my default template in my profile.But while executing the script,it takes the AddThis default template as email template instead.How can i get My Email template as Default one?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_share = { url: "http://www.example.com", title: "test site", description: "Watch the AddThis Tour video.", email_vars: { note: "hai", url: "www.abc.com" } }
 </script>
 <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
 <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
 <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
 <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
 <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
 <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
 <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a></div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config ={"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
```

Comment: Please show us the related code-parts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to log into your addThis account and then:

Account->Settings->Profiles->(select profile)->(Go to the email templates setting section)-> ( select the default template).

And then make sure that the profile id that is attached to the template is the same one you are referencing in your html/js files.

Comment: I have attached my profile id Profile ID: 'ra-528dd02b38e0dbb5' to js.But still I have the same issue. <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-528dd02b38e0dbb5"></script>